# NHibernate and HasMany mapping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

i have trivial mapping for two entities: poll and polloption

**Poll:**

```
public class PollMap : ClassMap<Poll>
{
    public PollMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Content);

        HasMany(x => x.PollOptions).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

**PollOption:**

```
public class PollOptionMap : ClassMap<PollOption>
{
    public PollOptionMap() {
        Id(x => x.Id);

        Map(x => x.Content);

        References(x => x.Poll);
    }
}
```

in test code im trying to remove the first polloption of poll entity

**Test code:**

```
    [Transaction]
    public ActionResult Add() {

        var poll = new Poll() {
            Content = "poll",
            PollOptions = new List<PollOption>() {
                new PollOption(){
                    Content="PollOption#1"
                },
                new PollOption(){
                    Content="PollOption#2"
                }
            }
        };

        GetSession.Save(poll);

        return Content("Added");
    }

    [Transaction]
    public ActionResult Removed() {

        var poll = GetSession.Query<Poll>().FirstOrDefault();

        poll.PollOptions.RemoveAt(0);

        GetSession.Update(poll);

        return Content("Updated");
    }
```

when the remove action fired it not deleting polloption from db instead it set null in my foreign key :(

[image: polloption table]

ps. google not helped

Answer (score 1):

`Cascade.All()` only deletes the child object if the parent is deleted. If you want the childs to get deleted when they are removed from the collection, you need `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()`.

Additional note: You also have to mark one side of your bidirectional association as `Inverse()`. More info about that here: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional

Comment: no im getting: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Comment: looks like child somehow connected to parent not with keys only

Comment: @Ilya Kogan, i modified my remove action for overwrote it in the list: http://goo.gl/VLJWo

Comment: @msony And why have you done that? It's clear that this exception is thrown because you HAVE removed the reference from the entity to the collection. Why don't you just remove the entry like you did in your original question?

Comment: @cremor cuz im using AutoMapper (http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and in code im doing this: http://goo.gl/hiLfs for avoid ton of code, when automapper fired it replace the list. so im asking how may i connect child entity to parent?